# Bootstrap modal cut in half

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal window set up, but when the button that activates it is pressed, the modal that shows up is cut in half, [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmwQT.png) In a smaller window the modal appears just fine. Excuse the code, it's kind of a mess.

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!doctype html>
<!-- ASSIGN OUR ANGULAR MODULE -->
<html ng-app="scotchTodo">
<head>
<!-- META -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><!-- Optimize mobile viewport -->

<title>OAMK Opinnäytetyöt</title>

<!-- SCROLLS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"><!-- load bootstrap -->
<style>
    html                    { overflow-y:scroll; }
    body                    { padding-top:50px; }
    #todo-list              { margin-bottom:30px; }


</style>

<!-- SPELLS -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script><!-- load jquery -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script><!-- load angular -->
<script src="core.js"></script>

</head>
<!-- SET THE CONTROLLER AND GET ALL TODOS -->
<body ng-controller="mainController">
<div class="container">

    <!-- HEADER AND TODO COUNT -->
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1>OAMK Opinnäytetyöt</h1>
    </div>

    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg text-center" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Lisää uusi aihe</button>

    <!-- TODO LIST -->
    <div id="todo-list" class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-10>

            <!-- LOOP OVER THE TODOS IN $scope.todos -->
            <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="todo in todos">
                <label>
                <h1>
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="deleteTodo(todo._id)"> {{ todo.aihe }}
                </h1>
                </label>
                <br>
                    {{ todo.kuvaus }}

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">   
  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p><!-- FORM TO CREATE TODOS -->
    <div id="todo-form" class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 text-center">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">

                    <!-- BIND THIS VALUE TO formData.text IN ANGULAR -->
                    <input type="text" maxlength="50" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Aihe (max. 50 merkkiä)" ng-model="formData.aihe">
                    <input type="text" maxlength="255"class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Kuvaus (max. 255 merkkiä)" ng-model="formData.kuvaus">
                </div>

                <!-- createToDo() WILL CREATE NEW TODOS -->
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="createTodo()">Lisää</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>

</div>

 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it possible your css on the `#myModal` is affecting it?

Comment: Without the CSS the modal still gets halved, it's just in a different place: i.stack.imgur.com/srpAf.png

Comment: Regarding your update, with this exact code, it works fine... Doesn't it? I can't reproduce your errors... http://imgur.com/CD9yQw7 This is in Chrome - Maximized. It also works fine in I Explorer

Comment: Okay then the problem is elsewhere. I added the whole index.html code to the OP.

Comment: First thing I notice is that you have a redundant load of `bootstrap.min.css`. Remove the last one (version 3.0.0) and keep the first one (version 3.3.6) ! It still works fine for me, so I guess it has something to do with either you JS or the CSS I just mentioned (are you ever overriding the modal somewhere)??? Have you by yourself tried making an empty workspace, with ONLY the code you provide here? It looks like it's working pretty good!

Comment: I deleted the extra bootstrap.min.css and the modal works now! I really should have caught that myself :P Thanks for the help, chrisv! And sorry for the trouble...

Comment: Good good! Glad it worked out! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve with your CSS? Your code works very well without the CSS!

Check fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eoug80b8/

Isn't that what you're looking for? :P

If you have to use your custom CSS style, you should at least remove this line: `left: -100%;` since that will mess up some things!

New fiddle without that specific line https://jsfiddle.net/eoug80b8/1/

Also: If you go with the last solution, you should really reconsider using the `width: 140%;`, since it will probably move the close button outside visible area!

Comment: Yeah, the CSS is there just because I was trying if I could get the modal to show properly, but I removed it now. Without the CSS the modal appears on the far right but still gets cut in half, like [this.][1]  I also forgot to mention that the modal appears fine in a smaller window just like your fiddle. 


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/srpAf.png

Comment: Then I think we need to see the rest of your CSS. It sounds like you have a problem with either oversizing HTML or BODY element or something similar. The dialog should resize and be centered as long as you don't mess up the CSS. Check out the bootstrap CSS here (ctrl/cmd + F to find modal-lg or modal-dialog): https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css

Comment: Here's all the CSS I have, not a lot:

    html                    { overflow-y:scroll; }
    body                    { padding-top:50px; }
    #todo-list              { margin-bottom:30px; }

And then there's this, can this cause problems?

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><!-- Optimize mobile viewport -->

Comment: Update your OP, so everyone can find it! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and I solved it by adding

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" style="left:0% !important">
```

instead of

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
```

in the modal div

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else stubles across this question, I tested OP's code and had the exact same issue, but removing the modal-dialog class of the inner modal div fixed it. On the line `<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">`, I removed the modal-dialog class and the modal is no longer cut in half on the right side.

Alternatively, you could just close the modal-dialog div before the next div starts.