# Bootstrap modal randomly moved to right of screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I had a fully functioning sign in bootstrap modal, no changes to its css and one day it just appears in the picture, cut off  to the right. I have taken it out and copied in a modal from w3schools, as you can see, same result. any ideas? it is currently the w3schools code.

```
     <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

[link to image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ClkQ.png)

Comment: the code you provided doesn't reproduce the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: How to create a [mcve]

Comment: I know it doesnt reproduce the problem on anyone elses screen i took that from W3schools. I want the modal in the middle of screen where it would normally be but regardless what i do it stays cut in half -
 half- Its the same as this question and he never got an answer.--http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37655924/bootstrap-modal-cut-in-half

Comment: then what do you want us to do to help? YOu already have the w3schools example. If we give you demo code that works, say from w3schools, I'm assuming that won't work for you? How are we supposed to help? *"I want the modal in the middle of screen where it would normally be but regardless what i do it stays cut in half "* You said "regardless what I do" - **share what you did** and we can probably fix it.